# Can thinking sphinx be made to prioritize larger n-gram matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, thinking-sphinx, n-gram

I'm using the thinking-sphinx 2.0.1 gem with rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7.

I'm trying to improve search quality on my site, and I'd like to be able to prioritize bigram and trigram matches over non-contiguous multiword matches.

In case I have my terminology wrong, here's an example: For the query "green tomato", I'd like "fried green tomato sandwich" to be recognized as a better match than "green bean and tomato salad".

Ideally, I'd like to control the strength of this effect, and perhaps to be able to value proximity of the constituent words continuously (i.e. the further apart the matched words are, the weaker the overall match).